# Multiple element with relative position

Tags: css

I have multiple elements with relative position and their child's having an absolute position. The moment is applied for all child absolute position, all elements are stacked on the same top and left value.

Can anyone explain me, what is the logic here?

Comment: Please share your code. You might be using a common class name for all elements & providing css to that. in this case the css will be effected to all elements with same calss

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

At the bellow image, the difference between the Relative and absolute position shown
The point is that in the relative position: element position set according to the other elements that are in the page
and
For absolute position: element position set according to the window not any element in the page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when I applied for the absolute position I came out of parent and parent height and width become Zero. :D